# enabling opcache on mac catalina, php 7.4 installed with homebrew

Tags: macos-catalina, opcache, php-7.4

I've modified the php.ini file to enable opcode caching and restarted apache but it is nowhere in sight with phpinfo(). php -v says:

```
PHP 7.4.1 (cli) (built: Dec 18 2019 14:46:18) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

Most other examples I see form this command say something like "with Zend Opcache".

No other .ini files except the one at `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini` are being used, according to php.

I tried installing zend opcache with pecl but that says it's for versions 5.2.0 thru 5.5.0.

Searched through google for 30 min. but not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, got it. Searched for the `opcache.so` file in Finder and added it's path to php.ini:

`zend_extension=/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.1/lib/php/20190902/opcache.so`